# Mongo db left a big folder after remove

Tags: apt

I've removed mongodb `sudo apt-get remove mongodb` but then found its parts:

```
    root@vickers:/var/lib/mongodb/journal# ls -lh
    total 768M
        -rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 256M Nov 18 17:35 prealloc.0
        -rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 256M Nov  7 19:11 prealloc.1
        -rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 256M Nov  7 19:11 prealloc.2
```

It's so strange that it took so much space since I didn't used it much (just some tests in console).

How should I remove Mongo to force it remove all its parts?

UPD. Also tried `sudo apt-get purge mongodb`. The same

Comment: Not enough information, version of mongodb?, os info?, commands you have tried and their output?

Comment: Sorry, it is too late

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25516871) might work, `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/journal/*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the mongodb folder by just simply doing this:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `apt-get purge mongodb`.  If that still doesn't clean it up, just do a `rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb`

Comment: Both commands require `sudo`.

Comment: I tried this, folder still exists